# client/server logging module timeout for SocketHandler

Tags: python, logging

I'm implementing python `logging` module using the `SocketHandler` to log messages from multiple remote machines.

**Client Part:**

```
    ......

    if self.loggerHost == "localhost":
        self.loggerHost = socket.gethostname()
    .......

    self.logger = logging.getLogger(self.handleName)

    self.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    numberOfHandles = len(self.logger.handlers)

    # are there no handles in the logger
    if numberOfHandles == 0:

        self.loggerPort = logging.handlers.DEFAULT_TCP_LOGGING_PORT

        self.socketHandler = logging.handlers.SocketHandler(self.loggerHost, self.loggerPort)

        self.logger.addHandler(self.socketHandler)

    ......

    # send the new handle to Handle table 
    self.__NewHandle(paramsDict=paramDict)
```

The `__NewHandle` Method creates a new log:

```
def __NewHandle(self, paramsDict):

        .......

        # update logger with new log! (trace)
        self.logger.debug(xmlString)
```

**Server Part:**

```
 while not self.abort:

     rd, wr, ex = select.select([self.socket.fileno()],
                                       [], [],
                                       self.timeout)

     # we have a read list available to read and process
     if rd:
         self.handle_request()

     .......
```

**Question:**

When the server is available everything works grate and each log is recorded very fast ~0.1 [mS] BUT when the server is unavailable, logging is slow and the first log can take up to 1 [sec] This is unacceptable for production.

I can't find any `attribute` at the python docs that controls the timeout of the logging (**client side**)

So if i'll use `logger.debug("....")` it won't take too much time.

does any one know how can i set a timeout for the logging action? or even better to ignore it if there is no response for the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's better to ignore it if there's no response from the server, as you have no way of knowing when the server will come back online, and you don't usually want to hold the application up because of logging.

BTW the `SocketHandler`, when a socket connection attempt fails, tries to reconnect using an exponential back-off strategy, using the following attributes with their defaults

```
retryStart = 1.0
retryMax = 30.0
retryFactor = 2.0
```

So if socket creation fails, it will try again (on the next logging call) after `retryStart` seconds, and after each subsequent failure, the delay before retrying will be increased by `retryFactor` upto `retryMax`.

Comment: I see, i now found it at the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.handlers.SocketHandler.createSocket) do you think there is any option on failure to avoid the use of exponential back-off algorithm and just to ignore the logging request?

Comment: I just saw your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2220356/1982962) it solves my problem and guides what to do. thanks!